# Finding linear factors of a polynomial with multiple pronumerals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Hi I have the following question:

**Given that $P(x)=4x^4-4x^3y-7x^2y^2+4xy^3+3y^4$ can be expressed a product of 4 linear factors $ax+by$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Find the expression.**

First I thought that $P(x)=(ax+by)^4$ and expanded it to match up the coefficients to find $a$ and $b$. However, it was correct because after I expanded it, it did not get me $P(x)$.

How would I approach this question? Are there any useful theorems that can help me to find the 4 linear factors of $P(x)$? I tried using factor theorem but I can't find a factor that gives me $0$.

Thanks

Comment: First factor $4 x^4  - 4 x^3 - 7 x^2 + 4x + 3$

Answer (score 1):

Divide the equation 4x⁴ - 4x³y - 7x²y² + 4xy³ + 3y⁴ by y⁴

And let (x/y) = t.

Now, 4t⁴ - 4t³ - 7t² + 4t + 3

You've to factorise this equation. Now clearly t = ±1 is a solution.
hence, t² - 1 is a factor

so it can be expressed as (t² - 1)(4t² - 4t - 3).

Comment: Please use MathJax. https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't feel the need to is there any error in your system while reading it? Like any notation not visible?